# Auto Scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation

So I have a SingleChildScrollView() whose child is a Column() with different widgets inside it. I have 3 BUTTONS on the app bar. Each for 3 widgets I want to jump to.

***When I press the button, I want the UI to automatically scroll to the mapped Widget.*** Just like we see that effect in websites.

**How can I achieve this ?**

Comment: Are you using a `SingleChildScrollView`? You don't mention what's doing the scrolling.

Comment: I just realised that I didnt mention it. And Yes I use SIngleChildScrollView

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) and pass it to the `controller` parameter of your scrolling widget. Then you can use the `animateTo` method to animate to an offset.

Ex.

```dart
ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

//In build
SingleChildScrollView(
  controller: controller,
  child: ...,
)

//In each button onPressed/onTap
controller.animateTo(offset);
```

Comment: what if you want to access to that scrollController from another page? Let's say, I am in pageTwo and when I press a button I want it to push pageOne and scroll down to a certain position