# How to move up scrollable list of selectable items inside GridView.count() in the Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have too many selectable iconbuttons list arranged by GridView.count(). I want to change the scroll position (move up) when selecting one of the icon buttons. how can I do that?

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
  child: GridView.count(
    childAspectRatio: 0.95,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 3, vertical: 0),
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    children: <Widget>[...iconButtonsList()],
  ),
)
```

this is the result of my code :

[image]

Comment: It seems like you need to re-order your list after each item selection in a way that it actually shows the selected elements first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ScrollController and pass it to the controller parameter of your scrolling widget. Then you can use the animateTo method to animate to an offset.

```
ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

//In build
SingleChildScrollView(
controller: controller,
child: ...,
)

//In each icon onPressed/onTap
controller.animateTo(offset);
```

or you can use this package scroll_to_index: ^2.1.1

**All Credit goes to this answer:** [Auto Scrolling in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63219846/auto-scrolling-in-flutter)