# How do you autoscroll to a point on another page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In response to a reply given to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63219846/auto-scrolling-in-flutter/75534789?noredirect=1#comment132272725_63219942) the user [parkorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17681687/parkorian) asked:

> what if you want to access to that scrollController from another page?
> Let's say, I am in pageTwo and when I press a button I want it to push
> pageOne and scroll down to a certain position –

There was no answer on that page sadly, So my question:

I want the UI to automatically scroll to the mapped Widget [from another page]. Just like we see that effect in websites. Let's say, I am in pageTwo and when I press a button I want it to push pageOne and scroll down to a certain position

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a CallBack Function from your Page1 to Page2 and in your  Page2 you can call it like this:

```
callback.call();
```

In your callBack (which you define in Page1) you just say scrollController.jumpTo or scrollController.jumpToPage

Comment: Which doesn't really mean anything to me, because I don't have a callBack, so I guess I will have to scroll through a whole lot of documentation to find out what that is.

Most of what I see brings me back to "Page1," which I can do already.
I have to go to a specific "row" or "child" in Page1, not the top, which is something I could do with a simple hash tag in html.

Comment: A callback is just a function which you define in page1. Write a function named scrollPage(), inside you call scrollController.jumpToPage(positionToJump). This function is passed inside Page2 as a variable, name it for example scrollCallback. You can define function as variables like this: Function myScrollCallBack.  To call this function now from page2 to trigger the scroll on page1 you have use the variable with myScrollCallback.call();